# MongoDB Crashed,Not able to start it again

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb fail to start after showing this error...and not able to start it again..?Can u help me find out?

```
   *** glibc detected *** /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo: corrupted double-linked list: 0x000000000f750b50 ***
   Mon Nov 26 19:01:29 mongo got signal 11 (Segmentation fault), stack trace: 

======= Backtrace: =========

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x788d6)[0x2b2db94198d6]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7a841)[0x2b2db941b841]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x73)[0x2b2db941f603]
/usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pIN5mongo7BSONObj6HolderEE7disposeEv+0x12)[0x45bd92]
/usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_ZN5boost6detail12shared_countD2Ev+0x49)[0x45d319]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(exit+0xe1)[0x2b2db93da961]
/usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_Z10quitNicelyi+0x53)[0x458043]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfc60)[0x2b2db753fc60]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(kill+0x7)[0x2b2db93d4fe7]
/lib/libreadline.so.6(+0x25888)[0x2b2db889b888]
/lib/libreadline.so.6(rl_getc+0x5e)[0x2b2db889d9de]
/lib/libreadline.so.6(rl_read_key+0xf8)[0x2b2db889e0c8]
/lib/libreadline.so.6(readline_internal_char+0x61)[0x2b2db8889061]
/lib/libreadline.so.6(readline+0x55)[0x2b2db88895b5]
/usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_Z13shellReadlinePKci+0x8a)[0x45694a]
/usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_Z5_mainiPPc+0x1506)[0x45a1a6]
/usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(main+0x26)[0x45b1d6]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xff)[0x2b2db93bfeff]
 /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo[0x456449]

 ======= Memory map: ========
  00400000-0055c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 32385496     
   /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo    

   0075c000-00762000 r--p 0015c000 fd:03 32385496                                /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo
```

00762000-00765000 rw-p 00162000 fd:03 32385496                               /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo

```
 00765000-00767000 rw-p 00765000 00:00 0 
0f74e000-0f961000 rw-p 0f74e000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

2b2db730d000-2b2db732e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 32112840                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
    2b2db732e000-2b2db7331000 rw-p 2b2db732e000 00:00 0 
    2b2db7331000-2b2db7351000 rwxp 2b2db7331000 00:00 0 
    2b2db752d000-2b2db752e000 r--p 00020000 fd:03 32112840                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
     2b2db752e000-2b2db7530000 rw-p 00021000 fd:03 32112840                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
      2b2db7530000-2b2db7548000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 32112843                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
       2b2db7548000-2b2db7748000 ---p 00018000 fd:03 32112843                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
        2b2db7748000-2b2db7749000 r--p 00018000 fd:03 32112843                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
         2b2db7749000-2b2db774a000 rw-p 00019000 fd:03 32112843                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
         2b2db774a000-2b2db774e000 rw-p 2b2db774a000 00:00 0 
2b2db774e000-2b2db7836000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 32380634                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
        2b2db7836000-2b2db7a35000 ---p 000e8000 fd:03 32380634                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
2b2db7a35000-2b2db7a3d000 r--p 000e7000 fd:03 32380634                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
2b2db7a3d000-2b2db7a3f000 rw-p 000ef000 fd:03 32380634                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
2b2db7a3f000-2b2db7a55000 rw-p 2b2db7a3f000 00:00 0 
2b2db7a55000-2b2db7a58000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 32244866                   /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.42.0
2b2db7a58000-2b2db7c57000 ---p 00003000 fd:03 32244866                   /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.42.0
2b2db7c57000-2b2db7c58000 r--p 00002000 fd:03 32244866                   /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.42.0
2b2db7c58000-2b2db7c59000 rw-p 00003000 fd:03 32244866                   /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.42.0
2b2db7c59000-2b2db7c6d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 32244882                   /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0
2b2db7c6d000-2b2db7e6c000 ---p 00014000 fd:03 32244882                   /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0
2b2db7e6c000-2b2db7e6e000 r--p 00013000 fd:03 32244882                   /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0
2b2db7e6e000-2b2db7e6f000 rw-p 00015000 fd:03 32244882                   /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0
2b2db7e6f000-2b2db7e83000 r-xp 00000000 fd:03 32244880                   /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.42.0
2b2db7e83000-2b2db8082000 ---p 00014000 fd:03 32244880

```
      Mon Nov 26 19:01:29 mongo got signal 6 (Aborted), stack trace: 

      Mon Nov 26 19:01:29 0x45e03f 0x457694 0x2b2db93d4d80 0x2b2db93d4d05 0x2b2db93d8ab6 0x2b2db940fa9b 0x2b2db94198d6 0x2b2db941b841 0x2b2db941f603 0x45bd92 0x45d319 0x2b2db93da961 0x458043 0x2b2db753fc60 0x2b2db93d4fe7 0x2b2db889b888 0x2b2db889d9de 0x2b2db889e0c8 0x2b2db8889061 0x2b2db88895b5 
 /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x1f) [0x45e03f]
 /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_Z12quitAbruptlyi+0x324) [0x457694]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x33d80) [0x2b2db93d4d80]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x2b2db93d4d05]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x186) [0x2b2db93d8ab6]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6ea9b) [0x2b2db940fa9b]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x788d6) [0x2b2db94198d6]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7a841) [0x2b2db941b841]
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x73) [0x2b2db941f603]
 /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pIN5mongo7BSONObj6HolderEE7disposeEv+0x12) [0x45bd92]
  /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_ZN5boost6detail12shared_countD2Ev+0x49) [0x45d319]
```

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(exit+0xe1) [0x2b2db93da961]
       /usr/lib/mongodb/mongo(_Z10quitNicelyi+0x53) [0x458043]
       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfc60) [0x2b2db753fc60]
      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(kill+0x7) [0x2b2db93d4fe7]
      /lib/libreadline.so.6(+0x25888) [0x2b2db889b888]
     /lib/libreadline.so.6(rl_getc+0x5e) [0x2b2db889d9de]
      /lib/libreadline.so.6(rl_read_key+0xf8) [0x2b2db889e0c8]
      /lib/libreadline.so.6(readline_internal_char+0x61) [0x2b2db8889061]
      /lib/libreadline.so.6(readline+0x55) [0x2b2db88895b5]

**Any One have any idea?Why MongoDb Crashed?**

**OS:ubuntu 11.04 2.6.32-pony6-3**

**Mogodb:1.6.3**

**RAM:2 GB**

Comment: Throwing a badly formatted crash dump at us and expecting us to wade through it is poor form - you need to do some troubleshooting on your own and come to us with data.  [See here for some tips](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete lock file first located in  **/data/db/mongod.lock**.

Repair mongo by running following command in terminal

```
mongod --repair
```